# Can't implement inheritance when childs have different return types

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

In a chart generating project I have 2 classes. One is called BitmapChart and the other is called VectorChart. All of their properties are the same and they have the same methods (with different implementations though). There is one exception and that is the Generate() function. In the case of a BitmapChart object it returns a Stream and in the case of a VectorChart object it returns an XmlDocument.

At first I thought I should use Inheritance, both are 'Charts' and they share the same properties and methods. But then I realised polymorphism is not possible because of the different return types.

Is there an OO principle or design pattern I'm missing to make my code more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> same methods (with different implementations though).

Create an **interface** for these methods if you want to be able to use them interchangable. But as the `Generate()` methods do different things, don't include them in the interface. You probably even should name them different, i.e. `GenerateStream()` and `GenerateXml()`

As for the intersection of implementation (same properties and maybe parts of the methods), you should try to separate logic and presentation. So this might be a better approach for you:

```
+--------+        +----------------------+
| Chart  |        |     <<interface>>    |
|--------|        |     ChartRenderer    |
|-data   |        |----------------------|
|-labels |        |+setChart(Chart chart)|
|- ...   |        |+...                  |
+--------+        +----------------------+
                        ^         ^
                        |         |
       +----------------+--+   +--+----------------+
       |BitmapChartRenderer|   |VectorChartRenderer|
       |-------------------|   |-------------------|
       |+generateStream()  |   |+generateXml()     |
       +-------------------+   +-------------------+
```

Comment: I like this solution, I can now treat the chart's equally until the rendering. Just out of curiosity, is this some sort of factory pattern?

Comment: No but it's similar to the Strategy pattern. In the real Strategy pattern you would implement a `Chart.render()` method and pass a `ChartRenderer` instance to `Chart` but I would not introduce this dependency without need. This solution has no pattern name that I know of, it's just plain decoupling.